# Toggling subnav and newsticker

Tags: jquery, menu

I want to show a newsticker by default, but its positioned in a way that when hovering a menu, the subnav should replace the newsticker. But I can't quite get it working:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rd9jS/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav > ul > li').mouseover(function () {
        $('#news').hide();
        $(this).parent().find("ul.children").not($('ul.children', this)).hide();
        $('ul.children', this).slideDown();
    });
    $('#nav .children').mouseleave(function (e) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('#news').slideDown();
        },2000);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the anonymous function provided to `setTimeout`, `this` is not what you think it is. It is actually the global `window` object. One way to solve this is to store a reference to the context where the function is created.

```
$('#nav .children').mouseleave(function (e) {
    var $children = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $children.hide();
        $('#news').slideDown();
    ,2000);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

MDN's [`"this"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Method_binding) documentation is a good reference on the subject and I quote:

> the object bound to this in the current scope is determined by how the current function was called